# Wi-Fi with HP Pavilion G7

Tags: 12.10, wireless, grub2, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion G7 Notebook computer and when I use ubuntu it starts up fine, and then when I get in I can't connect to wifi. I know the problem because it says something like "disconnected by hardware switch." I tried to turn on my hardware switch but it doesn't want to turn on (it is a button that is supposed to shine a blue light to show that it is on, but it shines a orange light which means it is off).

Answer (score 0):

Sir try following this link. Your Wifi has probably been blacklisted by Ubuntu. I am not sure why they allow this, but they have given us the solution. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx?lq=1) for more details.

my track in the woods as follows....

```
james@james-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$  sudo lspci -nn
[sudo] password for james: 
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0104] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1c12] (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:1c14] (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c49] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c03] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 05)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5209] (rev 01)

james@james-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23 linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23 linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic linux-headers-generic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 70.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Abort.
james@james-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$
```

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx?lq=1)
How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)

up vote 7 down vote favorite 
21
I'm having serious problems installing the Broadcom drivers for Ubuntu. It worked perfectly on my previous version, but now, it is impossible. I'm a user with no advance knowledge in Linux, so I would need clear explanations on make, compile, etc. I was following the instructions on the following blog, with no luck.
How can I get Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless working? 
Can someone help me?
Edit: For the command: `lspci | grep Network`, I get the following message:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
For the command: iwconfig, i get the following:
lo no wireless extensions. eth0 no wireless extensions.
```

When i follow the following steps (from the above link), there are a NO error message at all:
 1. Open the 'Ubuntu Software Centre' and search for bcm
 2. Uninstall the `bcm-kernel-source package`
 3. Make sure that the `firmware-b43-installer` and the `b43-fwcutter` packages are installed

Then, type into terminal:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep '8180|acx|at76|ath|b43|bcm|CX|eth|ipw|irmware|isl|lbtf|orinoco|ndiswrapper|NPE|p54|prism|rtl|rt2|rt3|rt6|rt7|witch|wl'
```

(you may want to copy this) and see if the term blacklist bcm43xx is there
if it is, type

```
cd /etc/modprobe.d/ and then sudo gedit blacklist.conf
```

put a # in front of the line: blacklist bcm43xx
then save the file (I was getting error messages in the terminal about not being able to save, but it actually did save properly).
reboot 'End of procedure'
Before (not Ubuntu 11.04), if I wanted to connect wireless, I just went to the icon at the upper side of the screen, click, showed ALL the wireless network available, and done.

```
james@james-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep '8180|acx|at76|ath|b43|bcm|CX|eth|ipw|irmware|isl|lbtf|orinoco|ndiswrapper|NPE|p54|prism|rtl|rt2|rt3|rt6|rt7|witch|wl' 
# which ath5k cannot recover. To prevent this condition, stop 
blacklist ath_pci 
blacklist eth1394 
# replaced by p54pci 
blacklist prism54 
# replaced by b43 and ssb. 
blacklist bcm43xx 
blacklist uart6850 
blacklist twl4030_wdt 
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf 
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the 
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first 
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi. 
remove iwlwifi \ 
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ 
james@james-HP-Pavilion-g7-Notebook-PC:~$
```

gedit

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by 
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the 
# device instead. 

# evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly 
blacklist evbug 

# these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred 
blacklist usbmouse 
blacklist usbkbd 

# replaced by e100 
blacklist eepro100 

# replaced by tulip 
blacklist de4x5 

# causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces 
blacklist eth1394 

# snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much 
# hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810) 
blacklist snd_intel8x0m 

# Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device) 
blacklist snd_aw2 

# causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306) 
blacklist i2c_i801 

# replaced by p54pci 
blacklist prism54 

# replaced by b43 and ssb. 
#blacklist bcm43xx 

# most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565) 
blacklist garmin_gps 

# replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721) 
blacklist asus_acpi 

# low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes 
# hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969) 
blacklist snd_pcsp 

# ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a 
# nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010) 
blacklist pcspkr 

# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture 
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver 
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its 
# really needed. 
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following command in terminal; rfkill unblock wifi. After that turn off your wifi switch and then back on. If that doesn't work, go to the network setting in the upper right corner of your screen with the notification icons. unenable the networking and do the command "rfkill unblock wifi", after that renable the networking.